# What are the non-identity symmetries of the determinant in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$?

Tags: determinant, symmetry, invariant-theory

I am curious if the determinant has any symmetries (i.e. transformational invariants). That is mappings $f: \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that

$$\det (f(X)) = \det (X)$$

notwithstanding the identity map. The map $f$ doesn't necessarily need to be representations or actions of well-known algebraic structures such as groups.

Neither [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) or [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Determinant.html) give any examples.

What are the non-identity symmetries of the determinant in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$?

Comment: Any mapping with determinant 1 should suffice.

Comment: @ilikemath Ah right, I forgot about the $\det (AX ) = \det (A) \det (X)$ property! Thanks. Feel free to post this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The determinant is invariant under [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) $X \mapsto X^T$ and under [conjugation / similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) $X \mapsto AXA^{-1}$. These are probably the most well-known examples and are distinguished by the fact that they play the most nicely with multiplication: transpose reverses multiplication and conjugation preserves it. (And [Wikipedia mentions this fact about the transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Transpose). [And about conjugation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Abstract_algebraic_aspects) but you have to scroll down further.) (And Mathworld mentions both of these facts as well.)

More generally the determinant is invariant under $X \mapsto AXB$ as long as $\det(A) \det(B) = 1$; this describes all linear maps leaving the determinant invariant. Most of these don't play nicely with multiplication though. This includes row and column operations as a special case (except the ones involving multiplying by a scalar), which is a common thing to play around with when evaluating determinants.

Much dumber examples preserving even less structure are possible, especially if you don't require $f$ to be invertible. For example, we can take $f(X)$ to be any block matrix of the form $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} \det(X) & 0 \\ 0 & g(X) \end{array} \right]$ where $g(X)$ is an arbitrary $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix with determinant $1$. This isn't really good for anything, though, and in particular is totally unhelpful for evaluating determinants since we have to know what the determinant is already.